# "str" object is not callable, In Python classes

Tags: python

I'm getting this error when I input `a` or `b` or `c` into `choice1`'s input:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

This is my code:

```
class a:
    name = "option a"
class b:
    name = "option b"
class c:
    name = "option c"
choice1 = input("input: ")
choice = choice1()
print(choice.name)
```

Comment: `a` (class) is not the same as `"a"` (string) in the code. `input` gives you the latter.

Comment: You'll find this useful: https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like matszwecja said your input is a string and not callable.
Also you are trying to execute a string with `class.name` in your class `a` which is not possible.
If you really want to use classes it would look like this.

```
class a:
    def name(self):
        print("option a")
class b:
    def name(self):
        print("option a")
class c:
    def name(self):
        print("option a")

choice1 = input("input: ")
if choice1 == "a":
    class_a = a()
    class_a.name()
```

However you should use if-statements and/or functions.